# Rails: How to define routes when include a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, routes

I want to define a new routes when a module be included, I try the following code but it didn't work:

```
included do
  ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.draw do
    get "test" => "public#test"
  end
end
```

Please correct me, thanks!

Comment: what version of rails are you using?  Rails 4.2?